# Where are pip packages installed if you run "sudo pip install --user <package_name>"?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

Does the --user flag do anything if you run pip with sudo, as in:

`sudo pip install --user <package_name>`

Where will the package install, and what will the permissions on it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man 1 pip-install`:

> **--user** Install to the Python user install directory for your platform. Typically **~/.local/**, or %APPDATA%Python on Windows. (See the Python documentation for site.USER_BASE for full details.)

Where `~` represents the home directory of the effective user.

If you run it using `sudo` (make the effective user the root user), the package will be installed in the home directory of the root user, which on most distributions equates to `/root/`, making the final install path `/root/.local/`.

Comment: I saw this, but it is still unclear to me where ~ will be if you run the command with sudo. Will running it with sudo change the meaning of ~?

Comment: So I was a bit skeptical, and decided to try this, however it did not install to the root user home directory, it installed to my home directory. I verified this using pip show before and after installing a new package using `sudo pip install --user <uninstalled_package>` I don't think that using sudo will change the meaning of ~. You can also verify that ~ is not changed by running sudo echo ~.

Comment: Regarding the `sudo echo ~` example: `~` is just a shell variable that is replaced with the path of the home directory of the currently controlling user. It is replaced by the shell with the full path of the home dir before the actual command is run, and so the full command being executed is actually (example username): `sudo echo /home/alex`.

If you want to see that `/root` is actually the home dir, try running: `su -c "echo ~"`. That will start a new shell with the root user as the controlling user and won't replace `~` using the current shell. It prints `/root` as expected.

Comment: Also, instead of using `pip show`, install the package as the root user again and check the contents of `/root/.local/lib/python*/`, you'll most likely find the package there.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the info about how ~ works. However I checked and the /root/.local directory does not exist after the install, but the package did not exist in my user .local directory before the install, and after the install the package was in my user .local directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202685/discussion-between-alex-mussell-and-bool3max).